# Use generic type as a static member of base class

Tags: c#, static-members, generic-collections

I have a static member in the base class of type:

```
private static Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>> cachedList;
```

This generic member should be available in all derived classes.  I'm not sure how to solve it.

EDIT
change member to protected, does not cure my problem.
for more clarification, I used this line of code

```
    public static void Cache(bool cached)
    {
        string value = typeof(T).ToString();

        if (cachedList == null)
            cachedList = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>>();
        ///some other things
    }
```

But every derived class has their own copy of `cachedList` and every classes returns "true" for the statement of `cachedList == null`

Comment: if your member is private, how is it going to be accessible to the derived classes? maybe you should make it protected.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect the issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to create a static member of a generic class which is shared across all specializations (i.e. all values of `T`)? If so, read on:

You can't do this directly, however you could add an extra base class that your base class inherits from:

```
public class NonGenericBase
{
    private static Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> cachedList = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>();

    protected static IEnumerable<T> GetCachedList<T>(string key) {
        return (IEnumerable<T>)cachedList[key];
    }

    protected static void SetCachedList<T>(string key, IEnumerable<T> value)
        where T : class
    {
        cachedList[key] = (IEnumerable<object>)value;
    }
}
```

And then wrap the usage of `GetCachedList` and `SetCachedList` in the generic derived class.

Answer (score 4):

Make this member [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of private. In this way you will be able to access *exactly* same dictionary instance within any derived type.